# What is the reliable way of getting each user's .ssh directory from bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, hosts

I can parse the /etc/passwd with augtool:

```
myuser=bob
usershome=`augtool -L -A --transform "Passwd incl /etc/passwd" print "/files/etc/passwd/$myuser/home" | sed -En 's/\/.* = (.*)/\1/p'`
```

...but it seems a little too convoluted.

Is there any simple, dedicated tool for displaying users'home (like `usermod` can be used to *change* it)?

Comment: Are you looking for a puppetized answer?

Comment: @mgjk No, I know how to do it on puppet. In fact I need this answer to write a bootstrapping script that sets up a puppetmaster on a LXC container :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should never parse `/etc/passwd` directly. You might be on a system with remote users, in which case they won't be in `/etc/passwd`. The `/etc/passwd` file might be somewhere else. Etc.

If you need direct access to the user database, use `getent`.

```
$ getent passwd phemmer
phemmer:*:1000:4:phemmer:/home/phemmer:/bin/zsh

$ getent passwd phemmer | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'
/home/phemmer
```

However there is also another way that doesn't involve parsing:

```
$ user=phemmer
$ eval echo "~$user"
/home/phemmer
```

The `~` operator in the shell expands to the specified user's home directory. However we have to use the `eval` because expansion of the variable `$user` happens after expansion of `~`. So by using the `eval` and double quotes, you're effectively expanding `$user` first, then calling `eval echo "~phemmer"`.

Once you have the home directory, simple tack `/.ssh` on to the end.

```
$ sshdir="$(eval echo "~$user/.ssh")"
$ echo "$sshdir"
/home/phemmer/.ssh
```

Comment: Great answer with all the polishing that includes the `awk` magic (which I never truly understood)

Comment: Is it always safe to assume that the sshdir will be `~/.ssh`? Can that be changed by a configuration setting anywhere or is it hardcoded into ssh?

Comment: It is a default, that can be changed in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `sshd_config`; at least on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for $myuser's home dir ?

```
 awk -F: -v user=$myuser '$1==user { print $6 ;}' /etc/passwd
```

you can use

```
 awk -F: -v user=$myuser '$1==user { printf "%s/.ssh\n",$6;}' /etc/passwd
```

to get .ssh dir.